# how to rsync sync between two servers web directory?

Tags: sync, rsync

I would like to know can I sync two server's folders like server 1 plugin updated should reflect on server 2. If we do this from server 2 it should reflect on server 1.

What rsync command should I use for this ?

I have tried the below command

`r sync -avWe ssh --delete-before //public_html/ root@139.162.23.53:/home/public_html/`

But it deleted newly added files from both servers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602324/how-do-i-synchronize-in-both-directions (or just google "bidirectional rsync" or "two way rsync" for more)

Comment: You have told `rsync` to delete files on the remote system before transferring new/changed files from the local one. It's the wrong tool for bidirectional sync; you need to use `unison` or something similar. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A100397+unison on [Unix.SE]

Comment: What kind of syncing you would like? Mirror 1 on 2, or vice versa, or do both?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use rsync with a remote source and a remote destination. Assuming the two servers can't talk directly to each other, it is possible to use ssh to tunnel via your local machine.

you can use this

```
ssh -R localhost:50000:host2:22 host1 'rsync -e "ssh -p 50000" -vuar /var/www localhost:/var/www'
```

The first instance of /var/www applies to the source on host1, the localhost:/var/www corresponds to the destination on host2.
In case you're curious, the -R option sets up a reverse channel from port 50000 on host1 that maps (via your local machine) to port 22 on host2. There is no direct connection from host1 to host2.

**Original Source:** https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183504/how-to-rsync-files-between-two-remotes